# Menu com Polimorfismo

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, polimorfismo

Estou criando alguns exemplos para aprender polimorfismo mais profundamente, porem no código original, todas a funções funcionam corretamente.

Código original:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

class Mamifero
{
 protected:
   int idade;

 public:
   Mamifero(){}
   ~Mamifero(){}

   virtual void somMamifero() const
   {
     std::cout<<"\n\tSom de mamifero.\n";
  }
};

class Boi: public Mamifero
{
 public:
   void somMamifero() const
   {
    std::cout<<"\n\tMuu ..! Muu..!!\n";
   }
};

class Gato: public Mamifero
{
 public:
   void somMamifero() const
   {
    std::cout<<"\n\tMiAu ..! MiAu..!!\n";
   }
};

class Porco: public Mamifero
{
 public:
   void somMamifero() const
   {
    std::cout<<"\n\tOinc ..! Oinc..!!\n";
   }
};

class Cachorro: public Mamifero
{
 public:
   void somMamifero() const
   {
    std::cout<<"\n\tAu ..! Au..!!\n";
   }
};

int main()
{
  Mamifero* mamPtr;
  int op;
  while(op != 5)
  {
    std::cout<<"\n\t(1) Boi"
             <<"\n\t(2) Gato"
             <<"\n\t(3) Porco"
             <<"\n\t(4) Cachorro"
             <<"\n\t(5) Sair"
         <<"\n\tDigite: ";
     std::cin>>op;
   switch(op)
    {
     case 1:{
       mamPtr = new Boi();
       mamPtr->somMamifero();
       break;
      }
     case 2:{
       mamPtr = new Gato();
       mamPtr->somMamifero();
       break;
      }
     case 3:{
       mamPtr = new Porco();
       mamPtr->somMamifero();
       break;
      }
     case 4:{
       mamPtr = new Cachorro();
       mamPtr->somMamifero();
       break;
      }
     case 5:{
       std::cout<<"\n\tGood Bye\n\n";
       exit(0);
       break;
      }
     default:
       std::cout<<"\n\tOpção Inválida ..!!!\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Por conta disso, pensei em criar uma função chamada *menu*, e a mesma seria virtual e se redefiniria conforme fosse executado. Mas não estou conseguindo, o código compilou mas da o erro *segmentation fault*.

Tem como fazer alguma coisa parecida para que funcione num principio neste sentido, igual ao que estou tentando fazer no menu sem ser o que esta no primeiro exemplo?

Modificado com menu polimórfico dando erro:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

class Mamifero
{
 public:
   Mamifero(){}
   ~Mamifero(){}

   virtual void somMamifero() const
   {
     std::cout<<"\n\tSom de mamifero.\n";
  }

  virtual void menu() const
  {
   Mamifero* mamPtr;
  int op;
  while(op != 5)
  {
    std::cout<<"\n\t(1) Boi"
             <<"\n\t(2) Gato"
             <<"\n\t(3) Porco"
             <<"\n\t(4) Cachorro"
             <<"\n\t(5) Sair"
         <<"\n\tDigite: ";
     std::cin>>op;
   switch(op)
    {
     case 1:{
       mamPtr = new Mamifero();
       mamPtr->somMamifero();
       break;
      }
     case 2:{
       mamPtr = new Mamifero();
       mamPtr->somMamifero();
       break;
      }
     case 3:{
       mamPtr = new Mamifero();
       mamPtr->somMamifero();
       break;
      }
     case 4:{
       mamPtr = new Mamifero();
       mamPtr->somMamifero();
       break;
      }
     case 5:{
       std::cout<<"\n\tGood Bye\n\n";
       exit(0);
       break;
      }
     default:
       std::cout<<"\n\tOpção Inválida ..!!!\n";
    }
  }
  }

};

class Boi: public Mamifero
{
 public:
   void somMamifero() const
   {
    std::cout<<"\n\tMuu ..! Muu..!!\n";
   }

   void menu() const
   {
    Mamifero* mamPtr;
    mamPtr = new Boi();
    mamPtr->somMamifero();
   }
};

class Gato: public Mamifero
{
 public:
   void somMamifero() const
   {
    std::cout<<"\n\tMiAu ..! MiAu..!!\n";
   }

   void menu() const
   {
    Mamifero* mamPtr;
    mamPtr = new Gato();
    mamPtr->somMamifero();
   }
};

class Porco: public Mamifero
{
 public:
   void somMamifero() const
   {
    std::cout<<"\n\tOinc ..! Oinc..!!\n";
   }

   void menu() const
   {
    Mamifero* mamPtr;
    mamPtr = new Porco();
    mamPtr->somMamifero();
  }
};

class Cachorro: public Mamifero
{
 public:
   void somMamifero() const
   {
    std::cout<<"\n\tAu ..! Au..!!\n";
   }

   void menu() const
   {
    Mamifero* mamPtr;
    mamPtr = new Cachorro();
    mamPtr->somMamifero();
  }
};

int main()
{
  Mamifero *m;
  m->menu();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

É bem simples, não faça isso. Não faz o menor sentido colocar o `Menu()` dentro de `Mamifero`. Faz menos sentido ainda o método (não função) ser virtual e usar polimorfismo. O exemplo está ótimo como foi concebido originalmente.

Sugiro você aprender um conceito de cada vez, e depois de dominar um é que deve passar para outro. Me desculpe, mas da forma que está tentando, está "desaprendendo" e não vai evoluir. Aprender deve ser uma escada onde não pode pular degraus. Eu sei que todo mundo quer ver funcionando, ou seja, quer ver a prática. Mas sem dominar a teoria, não consegue programar direito, principalmente em orientação a objeto que é um conceito essencialmente teórico. Tem que aprender fazer o certo, não ver funcionando. O que funciona mas está errado serve para nada. Precisa apender de forma estruturada e com boas fontes.

Se ainda quiser ver "funcionando", basta inicializar a variável no `Main()` para que ela possa ter uma instância e chamar o método `Menu()`. Mas isto ainda está muito errado. Não vou corrigir, nem listar todos os problemas, inclusive no original, mas seria isto:

```
Mamifero *m = new Mamifero();
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4ayf1T). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dtmyoabf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/OOP/Polymorphism.cpp).

Comment: Exato. Concordo plenamente com o @bigown. O erro de execução é mesmo simples: você não inicializou a variável `m` na função `main`. Mas você tem alguns erros **realmente importantes** de conceituação aí. Se me permitem colaborar, a razão principal do porquê de não fazer sentido ter o menu na classe animal é: *esse não é um "comportamento" do animal*. Na OO você organiza em classes os comportamentos que fazem sentido em cada entidade. Seria mais correto você criar outra classe (UI, de "User Interface", por exemplo) que faria o menu e criaria o animal correto. Boa sorte com os estudos. :)

Comment: Ah, outra coisa: cuidado para não ocorrer na síndrome do martelo-e-prego (o ditado diz: "pra quem só sabe usar um martelo, todo problema é prego"). Polimorfismo é útil, mas não é solução pra tudo. Por exemplo, nessa outra classe UI que eu sugeri, você não necessariamente precisaria utilizar polimorfismo, ok? :)

Comment: sim eu sei porem mais é por uma questão de logica mesmo para saber se é possivel ou nao tenho outros exemplos aqui mais corretos estou fazendo este pra entender se  é possivem e mesmo que funcione entender nalogica o que realmente aocntece para que funcione....

Comment: @dark777 é o que eu falei, isto não está te ensinando nada, o polimorfismo que faz sentido e é obviamente possível, é o que tinha no exemplo original. O Luiz Vieira já deu mais umas dicas, eu nem falei nada, porque o exemplo (que nem estava no site) estava tão fora de propósito que achei que seria avançado demais.